# stacked canvas on one content canvas at the same window

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

if i have two content canvases and one stacked canvas at the same window is it possible 
to display this stacked canvas at only one specific canvas at the same window ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can show or hide any canvas programmatically using the `SHOW_VIEW` and `HIDE_VIEW` procedures.